# CSS alignment code and displaying data on next pane

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

[when I click on option 1 the data should be visible in next pane and vice versa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJWyy.jpg)

Whenever the user clicks on Option1 it should show data to next pane as given in the figure.
so for that what shall be done?

Comment: you need JavaScript for that

Comment: Can You please share piece of code for that it will really help me out

Comment: What you have here are relations between to different elements - 
You want to listen to a click event on option one and then trigger the content element to make the text to show.
Can you share your html code?

Comment: Ok I will try and if I am not able to do I will share the problem -Roysh

Answer (score 0):

Considering the Options as buttons

**asp code**

```
<asp:Button ID="Option1Btn" class="btn" runat="server" OnClick="showDivContent1" />
<asp:Button ID="Option2Btn" class="btn" runat="server" OnClick="showDivContent2" />
<div runat="server" id="option1Content" Visible="false">Some Content </div>
<div runat="server" id="option2Content" Visible="false">Some Content </div>
```

**Backend Code**

```
protected void showDivContent1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Option1Btn.Visible = false;
    option1Content.Visible = true;
}
```

Likewise, you can do for the 2nd option as well

```
protected void showDivContent2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Option2Btn.Visible = false;
    option2Content.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Option 1 and Option 2 is a button and when it is clicked the datagrid view is shown next to it.

Comment: So the dgv will serve as the divs mentioned here and upon a btn click, it will be shown.

Comment: Note that though the divs are already present in the container they are invisible and it's only a matter of choosing the appropriate div to be displayed depending on the button click

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="left-pan" style="float: left; border-right: 1px solid;">
                <div class="Option-1" onclick="Option1Click();">
                    Option1
                </div>
                <div class="Option-2" onclick="Option2Click();">
                    Option2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-pan">
                <div class="showOption1" style="display: none;">
                    This is Option 1
                </div>
                <div class="showOption2" style="display: none;">
                    This is Option 2
                </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript :

```
 function Option1Click() {
        $(".showOption1").css('display', 'block');
        $(".showOption2").css('display', 'none');
    }
    function Option2Click() {
        $(".showOption2").css('display', 'block');
        $(".showOption1").css('display', 'none');
    }
```